# Printing async threads IDs works randomly

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to create 10 async threads, each printing its thread ID:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex printMutex;

class GenerateAsyncs
{
public:
    explicit GenerateAsyncs () {};
    std::future<void> operator()() 
    {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, []
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(printMutex);
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
        });
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main thread id: \n" << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    futures.reserve(10);

    std::generate_n(begin(futures), 10, GenerateAsyncs());

    for_each(begin(futures), end(futures), [](std::future<void>& future)
    {
        future.wait();
    });
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The result is that a random number of threads prints to stdout - sometimes only the main's id number is printed, sometimes only a few threads get to print their IDs, and sometimes the program works ok, e.g.

```
Main thread id: 
140648182765344

Main thread id: 
139913261897504
139913245943552
139913229158144
139913170409216

Main thread id: 
139704927008544
139704911054592
139704843912960

139704852305664
139704877483776
```

Is there any sort of race which I can't see? What is causing the random behavior and how to fix it?
Should I modify the program to use threads instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `futures.resize` instead of `futures.reserve`. With reserve, the futures are generated but not inserted into the vector. Hence your foreach loop is not executed and the futures are not waited on.

Alternatively, you can use a `back_inserter` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/) which will resize the vector for you:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(futures), 10, GenerateAsyncs());
```

Comment: I've expected generate_n to fill the futures vector. Why doesn't it increment while adding new futures?

Comment: vector::reserve (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) does not create the elements, and it does not change the `end` iterator. It just makes sure there is enough space for them. vector::resize creates the elements and adjusts the size.

Comment: But why doesn't generate_n fill the vector with successive futures obtained from asyncs? I've used reserve to prevent relocating the vector, but hoped for generate_n to fill it with actual values.

Comment: generate_n does not modify the vector's iterators. Specifically, it does not change the size and the end iterator. It just assigns values to successive locations, starting from the one you gave it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've missed that. An warning message would be helpful in that kind of situation. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianKramer: Depending on your compiler, there may be a way to enable "checked iterators" or equivalent functionality in development builds. Other than that, it's the normal C++ philosophy of having as little overhead as possible.